# How to specify javax.persistence @Entity annotated classes in generics?

Tags: generics, spring-data-jpa, jpa

I want to write functions that act on classes that e.g. extend from Spring `JpaRepository<TestEntity, Integer>`.

I tried:
Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity; 
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    Integer a;
    Integer b;
}
```

Repo:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity,Integer> {}
```

A Service class looks e.g. like so:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
public class TestEntityService {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

    private Function<? extends JpaRepository<? extends Entity, Integer>, Boolean> doSomeThing = integerJpaRepository ->
        integerJpaRepository.findAll().isEmpty();

    public Boolean dbIsEmpty(){
        return doSomeThing.apply(testEntityRepository);
    }
}
```

However, I get an error in Intellij:

> apply
>   (capture < ? extends org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository< ? extends javax.persistence.Entity,java.lang.Integer>>)
>   in Function cannot be applied
>   to
>   (.java_tests.database.TestEntityRepository)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Function<? extends JpaRepository<? extends Entity, Integer>` your TestEntity must **extend** or **implement** Entity, not **be annotated by** Entity.

General approach to do this is to create interface (or abstract class) and make `TestEntity` implement (or extend) it.

```
public class BaseEntity { ... }

public class TestEntity extends BaseEntity { ... }
```

and method

```
//---------------------------------------------------vvvvv-------
private Function<? extends JpaRepository<? extends BaseEntity, Integer>, Boolean> doSomeThing = integerJpaRepository ->
        integerJpaRepository.findAll().isEmpty();
```

Comment: This is not a general question, I speak about the Entity annotation from `javax.persistence`. I just don't know what's going on behind the sense of `@Entity`, so I can't figure the basic class. However, even if I define a useless, empty helper class like `@Entity public class BasicEntity ` and let the rest extend from it, I still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, removing `? extends` before `JpaRepository` helped, to make the workaround with an empty helper class work. However, that's still not a really nice solution, since I still can't define general functions for @Entity annotated classes, but need to extend from another basic class everywhere in my code.